# What's new in SMAPI 5.5?

Tags: sonos

Sonos 5.5 beta seems to have changed SMAPI somehow. Spotify for example seems to know the local time of the client, as it changes its response to getMetadata("root") depending on it, but as both the Spotify uris are https I can't sniff them to see. Anyone know what has changed?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done today by looking at the Client's IP address to determine their geographic location.  By refreshing the catalog (via getLastUpdate) at a regular interval you are able to update the root browse as you see in Spotify, Google and Songza to provide time specific playlists or radio.

Comment: Thanks. I am not writing a service, I am consuming Spotify via SMAPI. When the 5.5 controller does the call, Spotify "knows" my local TZ. When my code tries to do the same call (from the same IP addr), the TZ is wrong so the top item of "root" comes out wrongly. For example, right now 5.5 says "Soundtrack your evening", but when I try the same call from my code I get "Can't sleep, we've got you covered" ie it thinks it is later (EST I guess, but I am PST). What am I missing in the getMetadata call that is being used to detect the local TZ?

Comment: As you asked in another thread the TimeZone is in a new Context header.  Given that the format of this will change we are not yet ready to publish this as we are very likely to break implementations when we finalize the format of the header.  I suggest using customsd.htm to turn the header on for a simple service behind http to view the format.

Warning the current format WILL change and is unlikely to be backward compatible.

Comment: Ah yes, I see it now, thank you so much. Glad these two mysteries worked out to be connected.